# Text widget in Tk won't scroll

Tags: widget, scroll, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am creating a Tk toplevel window with a lot of widgets that wont fit into a single screen, so I decided to add a vertical scrollbar to my window. The base of my GUI was toplevel window $w and frame $w.baseframe.

When I found out that frames in Tk cannot be scrollable and I also can't use the BWidgets scrolledframe, I decided to go with a scrollable Text widget $w.text instead of my $w.baseframe frame. I put all my children widgets into it and added a vertical scrollbar like this:

```
text $w.frame -yscrollcommand {$w.scrollbar set}
scrollbar $w.scrollbar -command {$w.text yview}

<here I set all my other widgets>
<here I pack all my other widgets into the $w.text>

pack $w.scrollbar -side right -fill y
pack $w.frame -side left -fill both -expand 1
```

When I run the script, all the widgets are displayed correctly in the Text widget, I can see the vertical scrollbar on the right side of the window, but the scrollbar doesent do anything, It doesent scroll up or down and half of my widgets are invisible, because the toplevel window is simply too tall.

Thank you for your advice!

EDIT

This is a very simplified version of my code. I add 200 buttons in a single column. When I run thius code, I see a toplevel window streatched from the top of my screen to the bottom, I see a scrollbar on the right but it isn't working.

```
set w .testwindow

catch {destroy $w}
toplevel $w
wm title $w "title"
text $w.text -yscrollcommand {$w.scrollbar set}
scrollbar $w.scrollbar -command {$w.text yview}

for {set i 0} {$i < 200} {incr i} {
    frame $w.text.$i
}

for {set i 0} {$i < 200} {incr i} {
    button $w.text.$i.btn -text "btn $i"
    pack $w.text.$i.btn
}

for {set i 0} {$i < 200} {incr i} {
    pack $w.text.$i
}

pack $w.scrollbar -side right -fill y
pack $w.text -side left -fill both -expand 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be running fine, but I think that you forgot to change the names of a few variables, for example, your text widget is called `$w.frame` so your scrollbar should be set to this instead of `$w.text`:

```
scrollbar $w.scrollbar -command {$w.frame yview}
```

When I run the above with this amended line, it works fine for me.

---

EDIT:

Here is a similar text widget with the buttons:

```
set w .testwindow

catch {destroy $w}
toplevel $w
wm title $w "title"
text $w.text -yscrollcommand {$w.scrollbar set}
scrollbar $w.scrollbar -command {$w.text yview}

for {set i 0} {$i < 200} {incr i} {
    $w.text window create end \
      -create "button %W.click$i -text \"btn $i\" \
      -command {do stuff}"
    $w.text insert end "\n"
}

pack $w.scrollbar -side right -fill y
pack $w.text -side left -fill both -expand 1
```

Note that I am using `$w.text window create` instead which is specific to the text widget and which allows for embedding various other widgets in the text widget.

Also, if you are not using an 'external' variable like `$i` in the example, braces would avoid those backslashes:

```
    $w.text window create end -create {
      button %W.click -text "btn" -command "do stuff"
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you for the hint :) But it still isnt working, The scrollbar works, but not initialy, I can't scroll down to see the rest of my widgets, it's as if the window didn't know that there is more content to see. If I set focus to the text widget and type a lot of newlines, the scrollbar starts working, It scrolls in the text, but the widgets don't move.

Comment: I wrote an edit to my question that demonstrates my problem well. I use tcl/tk version 8.3, I have no choice in that, I cannot use a newer version.

Comment: @Tomáš'GunsBlazing'Frček Sorry, I was out for lunch. Hm, I have never used a frame in a text widget and I believe that's the problem here. I'll amend my answer to reproduce your buttons but with a working scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jerry. Im still new to tcl/tk, comming from compiled languages, all those different braces and quotes are a little confusing to me. I asume that the %W should probably be $w and aren't you missing a quote or brace somewhere in your code? Also what is the purpouse of the backslash at the end of the first line of the loop? Thank you for your paitence :)

Comment: @Tomáš'GunsBlazing'Frček No problem :) And yes, it can get a little confusing, but it'll become a bit more natural with practice. And no, the `%W` is really a `%W`. It refers to the text widget (it actually refers to the widget the command was called from, see [this doc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.3/TkCmd/bind.htm#M38). I actually copied and edited it from the Tk demos. And yes, I have added the quote back. I accidentally deleted it and removing the unnecessary parts :s

Comment: @Tomáš'GunsBlazing'Frček The backslash allows you to write the same thing on multiple lines; so you don't have to scroll left/right when reading/debugging your code. It's cleaner I believe :) (The backslashes for the quotes are to indicate literal quotes instead of quotes to end the string for the option '-create'. Double quotes allow substitution but not braces, and using quotes prevents you from using more quotes in the code! Hence why I used escaped quotes.

Comment: Thank you very much :) it seems odd though that frame isn't scrollable by default...

Comment: @Tomáš'GunsBlazing'Frček Hmm, I like to think of frames to be invisible containers to make things more organised. With that mindset, it wouldn't be useful to be able to scroll a frame, but rather its contents. I personally use `canvas` instead of `text` for my stuff. I feel there's more flexibility and I look back at the docs for refreshers, 'cause it's not easy to remember all of those syntax on the fly :)